# Power BI formatting

Tags: powerbi-embedded

How do I remove the header information from the bottom table so I can lay the percentages just under the month columns?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the header from your specific visual, Add a setting to your embed configuration to change the visibility of header for your required visual. Follow the below code snippet:

```js
let newSettings = {
    visualSettings: {
        visualHeaders: [
            {
                settings: {
                    visible: false
                },
                selector: {
                    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#visualSelector",
                    visualName: "Your_Visual_Name"
                    // The visual name can be retrieved using getVisuals()
                    // Hide visual header for a single visual only
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Update new settings in the report using `updateSettings()` as below:

```js
report.updateSettings(newSettings);
```

Please find the reference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/hide-visual-header#hide-all-but-one-visual-header